# How to run several docker images in one command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have docker-compose file with several services, such as nginx, web, redis, postgresql with their own `Dockerfile`. I always run docker-machine and then run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`. But now I work on older laptop (Ubuntu 16), which is not supporting HyperV techonology and I should run docker natively.

**Question**: How can I build and run several images using one command or what bash script should be to do so?

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      args:
        - REQUIREMENTS_FILE=requirements_all.txt
        - REQUIREMENTS_SRC_PATH=requirements*.txt
    env_file: ./web/.env
    volumes:
      - ./web:/code
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./web/static:/code/static
    depends_on:
      - web

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=administrator
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=love_docker
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data/

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - /data
```

Comment: Why would the same two commands not work now?

Comment: @TarunLalwani `docker-compose build && dcoker-compose up` work, but I don't know to run docker natively

Comment: So you mean you want run using `docker build ...` and `docker run ...` commands instead of using `docker-compose`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no-no, I want use  `dcoker-compose`, but I can't simply run docker-compose wihtout docker-amchine or docker running natively.

Comment: Did you install `docker` ? use `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com|sh` to install docker natively. You don't need `docker-machine` for that

Comment: @TarunLalwani, yes-yes. But if I simply run `docker-compose build` it displays: `Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run docker-machine start default.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152894/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-averin-maxim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to install docker natively on your machines

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

This will install docker but it won't be started yet. So you need to enable and start the service

```
# Enable docker to start on boot
$ sudo systemctl enable docker

# Start docker right now
$ sudo systemctl start docker
```